# Factorization of Polynomial $X^n -1$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have these two questions about the polynomial $f(X)=X^n-1 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

1. Assume $n$ is even. Show that $f(X)$ has two real roots. Factorise $f(X)$ into a product of irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

It is pretty easy to see that since $n$ is even $1,-1$ are the roots. My problem is with the factorization. I know that to factorize we have to have $f(X)=g(X)h(X)$, where $g(X),h(X)$ needs to be constants or units. I also know that $(X - a)(X - a^*) = X^2 - 2aX + a^2 + b^2$, where $a^*$ is the complex conjugate of $a$, but I'm unsure how to proceed.

2. Assume $n$ is odd. Show that $f(X)$ has $1$ real root. Factorise $f(X)$ into a product of irreducible polynomials of $\mathbb{R}[X]$.

Again the same problem. The root is $1$, but don't know how to go about with the second part.

Comment: Hint: what are the zeroes of $X^n - 1$ in the complex plane?

Comment: Do you mean the roots in the complex plane? That is e^((2*pi*i)/n)k, where k=0,...,n-1

Comment: Is there a general method to factorize $x^{n}-1$ over the reals? We have $$x^{10}-1=(x-1) (x+1) \left(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1\right) \left(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\right),$$ for example.

Comment: Yeah you can factorize $x^n-1$ to be $(x-1)(1+x+...+x^(n-1))$

Comment: And now I recommend replacing $x$ by $y:=x^2$, which then lets you factorize the above as $(y-1)(y^{k-1}...)=(x^2-1)(x^{2k-2}...$

Comment: To factorise into irreducibles you will have to work with cyclotomic polynomials, and the factorisation of $n$.

Comment: @Nikolaj Sure, but the second factor isn't irreducible isn't irreducible in all cases.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe Ohh, so when n is odd, you have only have the factor x-1, but when n is even you have the factors x-1 and x+1?